# how do you put more granular labels on yAxis in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to show more labels on yAxis, but I couldn't get it to work. My yAxis properties are as follows:

```
yAxis : {
                title : {
                    text : '%CPU Utilization'
                },
                 labels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    step: 5,
                    zIndex: 10
                    },
                showLastLabel: true,
                min:0,
                max: 100,
                plotLines : [{
                    value : 70,
                    color : '#FF3300',
                    dashStyle : 'shortdash',
                    width : 2,
                    label : {
                        text : 'Threshold',
                        align: 'right',
                        style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
```

I followed the documentation but does not seem to be working. I need a label at 0, 10, 20, 30, 40 (in 10 increments). Any idea whether this is doable in highcharts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you want to look at is the tickInterval property:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval

If you need irregular intervals, you can instead use the tickPositions property:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions

Or, if you need something even more complex, the tickPositioner function:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner

{{Edit:

remove the step property from your labels though - the step property tells the chart how many labels to skip when it draws them, not *where* to draw them.

Comment: @jbriggs, I have a very quick question. I like to put a link on the top right corner of the chart and when clicked on this link, I like to bring up another chart. Is there any documentation on how do this type of stuff?

Comment: depends on exactly what you want.  here are a couple of methods I have used to do this:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/TRd7f/6/  *||* http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/XQu8E/11/   If those aren't what you're looking for, start a new question

Comment: I created another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575082/how-do-you-create-a-link-on-hihgcharts-to-open-up-pop-up-window-with-another-cha