# how do you create a link on highcharts to open up pop up window with another chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am creating charts with highcharts. I like to put a link or button in a chart (possibley left-top corner) and when clicked, I like to call a function that shows another chart in a pop up window. Basically how they do it in highchart demo site. When clicke on the x on the top-right corner, go back to the orintal chart.

I was thinking about placing a subtile and place a click event to it, as below:

```
   subtitle: {
            text: '<span id="node42" class="node-link">by Server</span>',
            align: 'left'
            },
```

I have created a small java script like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $('node42').observe('click', function(event) {
      alert('my click handler');
    });

</script>
```

when clicking on the node42 link, it is not doing anything, any ideas?

Comment: You will need to create a "page" that contains the chart data you want to open in a new window (as your question title suggests). But, from your question text it looks like you want to open up a new detailed chart on the same page as the original chart. Which is it?

Comment: @wergeld, I modified my original post, but not quite there, any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: @wergeld, when clicked on the link on located on highcharts, I would like to open up a pop up window with another chart.

Comment: I get "TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function" on your javascript. Can you set up a jsFiddle with your basic setup?

Comment: Why not something simple like: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/subtitle/text-formatted/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this:

```
subtitle: {
    useHTML: true,
    text: '<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">by server chart</a>',
    align: 'left'
       },
```

and in my function

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function myFunction() {
           create the highchart syntax here
       }
  </script>
```